# how to show dropdownbox value in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have one dropdown box in html, base on selected option on dropdown i want to do some action i was tried code but it is giving me null pointer exception, 
Html Code:

```
<td>Status</td>
                <td> <select name="select">
                   <option value="Approve" name="optionvalue">Approve</option>
                    <option value="Reject" name="optionvalue">Reject</option></td>
                </select>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" name="btnLogin"/></td>
<tr>
```

jsp code:

```
String submit=request.getParameter("btnLogin");
 if(submit!=null)
{
String[] select_values=request.getParameterValues("optionvalue");
String select_value=request.getParameter("select");

if(select_value!=null)
{
for(int i=0;i<select_values.length;i++)
{
    if(select_values[i]=="Approve")
    {
         out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.write("alert('You are selected :" + select_values[i] + "')");
   out.println("</script>");

    }
    else if (select_values[i]=="Reject")
    {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.write("alert('You are selected  :" + select_values[i] + "')");
   out.println("</script>");

    }
}
  }
  }
```

Comment: You are mixing JSP and JS code. try to normalize your problem. What do you want? Do you want to sent-over the selection data to the server instantly and take action on behalf? Or you just want to run A JS action on front end and you dont have to aware the backend about this ?

Comment: i want selection data to server and take action bases on selection option like insert or update

Comment: I mean you will take action when the option is chosen and submit button is clicked, right? Are you using any Servlet to handle the submission ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud : yes , and im not using any servlet for this, try to handle directly in jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[option HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) doesn't have name attribute so it's ignored and `request.getParameterValues("optionvalue")` will be always null.

Also you have duplicate code and need to compare string using `equals` method, therefore change your code to:

```
if("Approve".equals(select_value) || "Reject".equals(select_value))   {
   out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.write("alert('You are selected :" + select_value + "')");
   out.println("</script>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user7294900 i got as expected result :) thank you for answer